# How to convert the JSON in WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to pass my JSON as a object to a WSO2 ESB.
I am getting JSON like this:

```
'{FIELDNAME":"NAME",FIELDVALUE:"KISHORE"}'
```

This JSON I need to pass my ESB as a dynamic column. But Its accepting like JSON `{"NAME":"KISHORE"}`. How can I convert from above JSON to below one in WSO2 ESB. If I get above one I am unable to pass to proxy. If I get below one I will pass like this `(//name/child::text())` then I will get value as "KISHORE" I was tried with ENRICH mediator but its not working.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test_dynamic" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">

<target>
    <inSequence>
        <enrich>
            <source type="body" clone="true"/>
            <target type="property" property="RM"/>
        </enrich>
        <property name="RM" expression="//fieldname/child::text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="r_no" expression="get-property('R_no')"/>
            <property name="r_value" expression="get-property('R_value')"/>
            <property name="emp_d" expression="get-property('emp')"/>
            <property name="RM" expression="get-property('RM')"/>
        </log>
        <log level="full"/>
    </inSequence>
</target>
<description></description>

</proxy>
```

ANS: request, Envelope:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body><fieldname>e_no</fieldname><fieldvalue>5</fieldvalue></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: my query is like this (select * from emp where col=?; column will add as dynamically like select * from emp where ?=?; how i will handle in wso2 dss or wso2 esb

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send the JSON message like this:

```
'{"RECORD":{FIELDNAME":"NAME",FIELDVALUE:"KISHORE"}}'
```

then get the value by the "Property" mediator in WSO2 ESB, like

```
<property name="FIELDNAME" expression="//FIELDNAME/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property name="FIELDVALUE" expression="//FIELDVALUE/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link provided below by WSO2 explains the exact usecase which you are interested in solving

Steps:

1. Convert JSON to XML using the XSLT mediator
2. Use the Enrich mediator to replace the Body of the SOAP message

Follow this link for detailed info and actual proxy configuration

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Sample+440%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+XSLT